# Eclipse JDK 8 Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, configuration

I configured **jdk1.8.0_65** and when I try to build a project using **maven**, I get an strange error in console.

The same project was successfully build with my old jdk (jdk 7)

Below is the error.

[image]

I'm using the following **Spring Tool Suite, Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE**
and below is my jre configuration in Eclipse.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java -version'?

Comment: let me guess jre is missing here : '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java

Answer (score 2):

Please check you java installation because backward compatibility is always present in java releases.Some methods might be deprecated but are still supported.
If your project was compilable on Java 7, it would be surely compilable on java8.

Answer (score 1):

I have configured the jdk 64 bit version for my 32 bit operating system. This was the issue.